# Why is my Web api Application_Error not catching Exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, error-handling

I am using a .net framework web-api project and in my global.asax.cs file i have this:

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        var exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError(); // get exeption
        // log exeption

        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.StatusCode = 500;

        // if debug return detailed exeption else generic like below

        Context.Response.Write("Internal server error");
    }
```

I enabeled custom erros in webconfig:

```
<customErrors mode="On"  />
```

And in a controller endpoint I throw an exception:

```
 throw new Exception("test");
```

Result I see in the browser is :

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred."
}
```

Result I would have expected is:
what is written in the Application_Error method:

```
Context.Response.Write("Internal server error");
```

Something is not registering here, what have I missed?

Comment: Have you tried setting your debugger to Application_Error to check if it responds to an unhandled exception

Comment: @MukulKeshari yes, the breakpoint never gets hit.

Comment: @ThunD3eR do you have this `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;` line in WebApiConfig.cs?